# How to extract info from this format using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, zillow

I'm trying to make a web scraper for Zillow, and I have successfully found a way to obtain raw info from a Zillow search page. However, I am fairly new to python and very new to web scraping and have no idea how to extract necessary info from this. How should I go about doing this?

Portion of raw info here (from query Houston, Texas)
https://paste.ee/p/QyJJG

Current Code (just scrapes info from desired area and spits it out into console)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import random

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.zillow.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' + str(random.randint(1, 1000)), #randomint bypasses captcha
}


with requests.session() as i:
    #user input
    city = str(input("City To Search In: ")) + "/"

    #initializers
    page = 1
    end_page = 10
    url = ""
    url_list = []
    request = ""
    request_list = []

    while page <= end_page:
        url = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/" + city + str(page) + "_p"
        url_list.append(url)
        page += 1

    for j in url_list: #can change j to "url" if you want but i like "j" for simplicity
        request = i.get(j, headers=headers)
        request_list.append(request)

#another two initializers (seperating this felt more organized to me, sorry if it looks messy)
rawInfo = ""
rawInfoList = []

for request in request_list:
    rawInfo = soup(request.content, "html.parser")
    rawInfoList.append(rawInfo)

print(rawInfoList)
```

I tried using find() and findall() but I was pretty confused because it always showed no results. I need the listing address, rent zestimate, link, and zestimate/price of various listings in an area. All of the info needed is in the raw info paste, I just need a way to take it all out and make it more readable. I'm trying to make something that takes all of these different pieces of information then adds them to a separate list for each type of info (price, rentZestimate, etc)

Comment: Shouldn't there a forward slash between `city` and `str(page)`? Also, using f-string would look at lot cleaner (IMO). For example, `url=f"https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/{city}/{str(page)}_p"`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think the information you want is located at a different URL. For example when I go to `https://www.zillow.com/austin-tx/3_p/` it doesn't show the rent Zestimate nor the Zestimate/price. For this information, you have to click on the property card which redirects you to another url (e.g. `https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/9005-Ipswich-Bay-Dr-Austin-TX-78747/80104660_zpid/`). This is likely the reason the BS methods are not returning the expected output.

An arguable better way to get the info you want is by [reverse engineering](https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html) the website's request. Using my browser's Dev Tools, under the Network tab, I found that website sends a GET request to this [URL](https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A2%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22north%22%3A30.728145092457208%2C%22south%22%3A29.85779787256072%2C%22east%22%3A-97.26683659374999%2C%22west%22%3A-98.36546940624999%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A10221%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22isAllHomes%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sortSelection%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D&wants=%7B%22cat1%22:%5B%22mapResults%22%5D%7D&requestId=2); the response is a JSON file that seems to contain all of data you want (i.e. listing address, rent zestimate, link, and zestimate/price).

Use the `json` module, instead of BS, to parse the JSON file for the data you want.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import random

import json

def save_json_output(out_path, json_output):
    # save json file for easy access
    with open(out_path, mode='w') as file:
        file.write(json_output)

def get_json(url, request_headers):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=request_headers)

    # create json object
    json_obj = response.json()

    # creat JSON string with 4-space indentation
    json_string = json.dumps(json_obj, indent=4)

    return json_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    headers = {
        'authority': 'www.zillow.com',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' + str(random.randint(1, 1000)), #randomint bypasses captcha
    }

    url = "https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A2%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22north%22%3A30.728145092457208%2C%22south%22%3A29.85779787256072%2C%22east%22%3A-97.26683659374999%2C%22west%22%3A-98.36546940624999%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A10221%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22isAllHomes%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sortSelection%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D&wants={%22cat1%22:[%22mapResults%22]}&requestId=2"

    path = "C:/Users/uber/RandomScripts/data/zillow_data.json"

    listings_data = get_json(url, headers)
    save_json_output(path, listings_data)
```